# SynchronizationContext and Bookmarks in WF4

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am running workflows under asp.net and using SynchronizationContext to make the page "wait" for the workflow. Here is how I run the workflow instance under asp.net:

```
var workflowApplication = new WorkflowApplication(activity);
SynchronizationContext syncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
workflowApplication.Completed = delegate { syncContext.OperationCompleted(); };
workflowApplication.SynchronizationContext = syncContext;
syncContext.OperationStarted();
workflowApplication.Run();
```

In one of the activities I use a bookmark. Now I want the page processing to continue whenever I call CreateBookmark. I tried calling SynchronizationContext.Current.OperationCompleted() before setting the bookmark but that crushes asp.net site when the workflow resumes and completes (I think the workflow instance calls OperationCompleted again when it completes and the error raises)

How can I work with bookmarks under Asp.Net, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The Completed Property isn't being called when you persist the workflow with a bookmark, try adding this line after you've set up the completed property:

```
workflowApplication.PersistableIdle = args => {
  syncContext.OperationCompleted();
  return PersistableIdleAction.None;
};
```

This should then be called instead of completed, and the ASP.NET code should regain control. Change the PersistableIdleAction enum to whatever is required, I've just picked None for example code.